# Ruby on Rails method declared in model isn't accessible from link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

so I have 2 methods in one of my models. The model name is user.rb, and the class is User. Here are the methods I declared

```
  def follow(user_id)
     following_relationships.create(following_id: user_id)
  end

  def unfollow(user_id)
     following_relationships.find_by(following_id: user_id).destroy
  end
```

And in my view I have a link_to that method like this:

```
= link_to 'Following', unfollow_user_path, remote: true
```

It is HAML but that shouldn't make a difference. When I start the server and try to go to someone's page I get this error:

undefined local variable or method `unfollow_user_path' for #<#:0x00563935a456e0>

This shouldn't be happening because I declared the method in the user model.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions defined in models have 0 effect on routing, you would need to modify your routes and your user controller to make this work.

you would need something similar to this.

```
#config/routes.rb 

resources :users do
  member do
    post :unfollow
    post :follow
  end
end
```

and then add ControllerActions for `#follow` and `#unfollow` to get the data from the view, and actually call the functions on the model.

read the rails routing tutorial (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)  for more information

Answer (score 0):

Yar is here.

What you trying to do in your example is to call model's method by ajax request, but it's not how it works. When you send AJAX or whatever request it first matches routes defined in `routes.rb` and finds corresponding **controller's method** to be called. So, you need to do this steps

0) Read about MVC and rails here or any other source you like http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

1) create new controller's methods which should be called when you follow/unfollow

2) add corresponding routes to `routes.rb` file like @Doon mentioned

3) inside this controller methods you can call your model methods